# Swift 3 Music app and synced letters

Tags: swift, random, graphics, character

I would like to place 12 characters, each in a different spot randomly spread across the storyboard.

Which is a good way to start out'? 
Using 12 text fields?

How could frames in that respect be useful. Maybe you have some basic information or any hints to get inspired with the possibilities Swift has to offer in that direction for commencing helpful studies

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you an idea of how this could be done in a very simple way.

If you had a single-view application with a view that was covering the entire screen (which should be included in the storyboard when it is created) that is linked with an IBOutlet like so:

```
IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
var labels: [UILabel]
var characters = ["2", "k", ...] //fill in as required

for character in characters {
    let labelWidth: Int = 20 //the width and height can be whatever you want
    let labelHeight: Int = 20
    let x = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(view.frame.width - CGFloat(labelWidth))) //must compensate for the height of the label so that it doesn't go off screen
    let y = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(view.frame.height - CGFloat(labelHeight)))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: Int(x), y: Int(y), width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight))
    label.text = character
    labels.append(label)
    view.addSubview(label)
}
```

What this does is sets a random number to your x and y values (which is less than the size of the view). These values are then used when initializing the labels' frame, providing it with a random location on the screen. This is done 12 times, based on the size of your character array.

Again, this is just the bare-bones for this type of idea, but I hope it helps.